# Data Storage in Memtables and SStables in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

I have a `Keyspace` with `RF=2`. Now before the data is flushed it is in `memtables` and there is only one `memtable` per table/column-family in Cassandra.

Since, there is only one memtable per column-family in cassandra and I have assumed the RF=2. Does it mean the memtable has 2 copies of each row?

Also, if I do `nodetool flush` does the sstable which is created also has two copies of each record?

Answer (score 0):

A replication factor of 2 means that the data will be stored on 2 nodes.

The write path is as follows:

1. The client sends a request to one node which will become the coordinator for that write
2. The coordinator node sends the write request to all replica nodes simultaneously. The number of replica nodes is specified by the replication factor.
3. Each replica node receives the write request and does the following: write to the commit log, write to memtable, invalidate row cache and send acknowledge to the coordinator node.
4. The coordinator will wait for the appropriate number of ack specified by the consistency level of the write request.
5. The coordinator will send ack to client.

So, at some point in time during the write path your data will be in the memtable, but since you have rf = 2, that means that the data will be in different memtables since each memtable is on a different node.

The same is available for nodetool flush. The data will be flushed to different sstables since each sstable is on a different node.